# Angular modules based on conditions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-module

Is there a way to load/specify modules based on conditions inside a controller ?

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);

app.controller("DemoCtrl",["$scope",function($scope){
   var a = true;
   if(a)
     // Load "Yes" module to app
   else
     // Load "No" module to app
}]);
```

Comment: What precisely do you mean by `load modules`?

Comment: @charlietfl I mean specifying modules for app like ngRoute. Here, app uses ngRoute and i just want to add one more module to app based on a condition in controller

Comment: will need a third party lazy loader like ocLazyLoad. There is nothing built into core yet in `v1.xx` angular

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do this in Angular out-of-the-box, however you can consider using the [ocLazyLoad module](https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs).

The example given on the linked page shows how you could use it for your case:

```
myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($ocLazyLoad) {
    $ocLazyLoad.load('testModule.js');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, NO, at least out of the box with plain Jane Angular. You cannot load more modules into another module after that module has been defined. What you need to do is move the logic to conditionally load the module when defining your module.

The other option is to used the ocLazyLoad https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad tool to lazy load your modules.